# How to update multiple instances of user control using MVVM databinding WPF?

Tags: wpf, mvvm, wpf-controls

I have created a `UserControl` with a `ProgressBar` and a `Label`.

```
<Label Content="{Binding ElementName=UserControl, Path=StatusProperty}" Grid.Row="1" Height="28" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="76,0,0,32" Name="lblStatus" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Grid.RowSpan="2" />
<ProgressBar Grid.Row="2" Height="20" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="12,3,0,0" Name="pbCheckProgress" Style="{DynamicResource ProgressBarStyle}" Maximum="{Binding ElementName=UserControl, Path=MaximumProperty}" Minimum="{Binding ElementName=UserControl, Path=MinimumProperty}" Value="{Binding ElementName=UserControl, Path=ValueProperty}" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="156" />
```

Then I have created the following `DependencyProperties`:

```
// Dependency Properties for labels
public static readonly DependencyProperty StatusProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("Status", typeof(string), typeof(UserControl1), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata("", FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.BindsTwoWayByDefault));

// Dependency Properties for progress bar properties
public static readonly DependencyProperty MinimumProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("Minimum", typeof(double), typeof(UserControl1), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(0.0d, FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.BindsTwoWayByDefault));

public static readonly DependencyProperty MaximumProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("Maximum", typeof(double), typeof(UserControl1), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(0.0d, FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.BindsTwoWayByDefault));

public static readonly DependencyProperty ValueProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("Value", typeof(double), typeof(UserControl1), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(0.0d, FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.BindsTwoWayByDefault));
```

Now I would like to create multiple instances of this `UserControl` in the same page and update the `ProgressBar` from code behind using MVVM. But I could not figure this out. Do I need to have a ViewModel for the `UserControl` so that every instance will have its own copy of ViewModel.

Is there a way to update all the instances from the page ViewModel?

Thanks & Regards,
Bharat

Comment: ElementName should point to an x:Name attribute value, not an element type (UserControl, TextBox, etc)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand what you correctly, it sounds like you want to create a ViewModel for this `UserControl` and then have multiple instances of that ViewModel (one for each instance of the `UserControl` on the View).  If you had a single ViewModel with multiple `UserControls` bound to it, they would all show exactly the same thing.

It sounds like you already have a ViewModel for the Page, so you can simply add the ViewModel for the `UserControl` as a property of the Page ViewModel, like this:

```
public class PageViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private UCViewModel _ucViewModel;

    //Other ViewModel Code

    public UCViewModel UserControlViewModel
    {
        get { return _ucViewModel; }
    }
}
```

Where UCViewModel is the ViewModel for your `UserControl`.  Then, in your XAML, you simply bind to the properties on the UCViewModel, like this:

```
<local:myControl Status="{Binding UserControlViewModel.Status}"... />
```

If you have a collection of UCViewModels, you'd need to handle it a little differently, but the concept is still the same.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. This is exactly what I am trying to do. I have parallel running tasks and trying to show the progress of each task through User control (UC contains Label and Progress Bar). I will try your solution and then update this as solution.